# Soft Question: Combinatoric reading material

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation

I am curious if anyone can recommend a good introductory text on combinatorics in similar vein as Richard J. Trudeau's *Introduction to Graph Theory* put out by Dover.

For those who have not read it, it is a bit on the lighter side not something that would necessarily be used as a text for a course.

I am currently on break, I'd like to do a little bit of lighter reading on combinatorics. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIT has free lecture notes on combinatorics which are pretty concise and well written. I found it to be a good introduction (and I didn't need to attend the lectures to benefit from it).
You can find it [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/mathematics/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/lecture-notes/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read Ivan Niven's *Mathematics of Choice:  How to Count Without Counting*.  It is a brief, accessible introduction to enumerative combinatorics that I would recommend as preliminary reading for students preparing to take an advanced undergraduate course in combinatorics.  The text emphasizes problem solving and includes solutions to many of the problems.  It also has the virtue of being inexpensive.